# DropDownList Binding items

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, data-binding

I have DDL in custom control that in the default case I insert new item with certain value.
but in a certain case I insert another item and want to the previous item to be deleted.

I tried to remove the first item and insert the another
I tried to change text and value of the inserted item

the 2 ways failed because:
in the first load of page, it take the value of the first item and text of the second,
then if I select another thing from DDL and then return to my Item, it take its correct value.
I need the second to take the correct value in the first load of the page.

Comment: Please post the code that isn't working and show us what you've tried to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean exactly,but let me try to help.
Page Load, the DDL has Item 1 loaded e.g. ItemText:Stack ItemValue:Overflow

Then on some action the above is deleted and a new Item is Inserted?

If so, could you try somthing like,
VB

```
With me.DDL
'Remove all Items from the DDL
.Items.Clear()
'Insert New Items
.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("VALUE",TEXT"))
End With
```

C#

```
//Remove all Items from the DDL
this.DDL.Items.Clear();
//Insert New Items
this.DDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("VALUE", "TEXT"));
```